# Can I point a Heroku project to a Path in my Domain?

Tags: ruby, dns, heroku

If I have a project on heroku:

- http://martini.heroku.com

Can/how-do I point that to a path on my domain:

- [http://viatropos.com/martini](http://viatropos.com)

Is that possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No if You don't have direct control over server at viatropos.com. If You do have, then I think You could use some forwarding rules.

Comment: i figured, sunuva :).  oh well.

Answer (score 1):

No, you can't. You can only map entire domains since the configuration is based on DNS settings.